# How can I pass props to a component received from parent as a prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
import React from 'react'

const fruits = [
  { id: 1, text: `mango` },
  { id: 2, text: `apple` },
]

const Fruit = ({ fruit }) => (
  <div>{ fruit.id } - { fruit.name }</div>
)

const Fruits = ({ component }) => (
  <ul>
    { fruits.map( fruit => <li>{ component({ fruit }) }</li> ) }
  </ul>
)

export const Parent = () => (
  <div>
    <Fruits component={ <Fruit /> } />
  </div>
)
```

As seen in the example above, the prop can't be passed from the parent as the prop is obtained from an array of objects looped in the child.

When I run this code, it obviously throws the error:

> TypeError: component is not a function

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few options:

1. Clone the element and add props to it.

```
import React, { cloneElement } from "react";

export const Parent = () => (
  <div>
    <Fruits component={<Fruit />} />
  </div>
);

const Fruits = ({ component }) => (
  <ul>
    {fruits.map((fruit) => (
      <li>{cloneElement(component, { fruit })}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

I would generally avoid doing this. [cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) does have some uses, but it's not common to use it, so it may be unfamiliar and thus hard to understand and maintain. Plus, your scenario has better options i think:

2. Pass a component, not an element, and have the child turn it into an element

```
export const Parent = () => (
  <div>
    <Fruits component={Fruit} />
  </div>
);

const Fruits = ({ component: Component }) => (
  <ul>
    {fruits.map((fruit) => (
      <li>
        <Component fruit={fruit} />
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

This is pretty simple, but it does make the two components tightly coupled. Parent and Fruits need to be on the same page about exactly what props are going to be sent to the other component. I would use this approach if there's a limited number of ways you'll be using this, and so you don't mind if it's not very flexible.

3. Pass a function which knows how to create the element from the props, and have the child call that function with the props.

```
export const Parent = () => (
  <div>
    <Fruits component={(props) => <Fruit fruit={props.fruit} />} />
  </div>
);

const Fruits = ({ component }) => (
  <ul>
    {fruits.map((fruit) => (
      <li>{component({ fruit })}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

This reduces the coupling between the components, because Fruits no longer makes assumptions about what the name of the child component's props are. This approach is often called a ["render prop"](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html). I would use this approach if you need a higher level of flexibility.

Comment: Very well explained. I learnt more than I needed. Thank you very much, Nicholas.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
const Fruits = ({ component }) => (
      <ul>
        { fruits.map( f => <li><component fruit={</f>} ></li> ) }
      </ul>
  )
```

Comment: Doesn't a user-defined component have to start with a capital letter in JSX? (https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

Comment: Not creating component but using function parameter.

Comment: React doesn't let us do that unless we use cloneElement as in Nicholas's answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
import React from 'react'

const Base = ({ item }) => (
  <li>{ item.id } - { item.name }</li>
)

const BaseItems = ({ items }) => (
  <ul>
    { items.map((item, i) => <Base key={i} item={item} /> ) }
  </ul>
)

const fruits = [
  { id: 1, text: `mango` },
  { id: 2, text: `apple` },
]

const vegetables = [
  { id: 1, text: `potato` },
  { id: 2, text: `broccoli` },
]

export const Parent = () => (
  <div>
    <BaseItems items={fruits} />
    <BaseItems items={vegetables} />
  </div>
)
```

You can try this with simplicity.

Comment: I can't do that as the component passed from parent could be anything , like <Vegetables /> or <Beverages />

Comment: React components are for creating base prototype. Only data differs. You don't need to pass separate components for separate data.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I wasn't perfectly clear in the question, but in my case, the components that need to be passed might contain other elements like buttons, links and action dispatches and not just regular data.